Refreshing a pivot table on an Excel worksheet
I have been trying to refresh all of the pivot tables contained within an Excel worksheet using the Microsoft Graph REST API and the Microsoft Graph C# SDK. Neither approach seems to affect the Excel file I am trying to update. Here is the URL that I am using:
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{siteId}/drives/{driveId}/items/{fileId}/workbook/worksheets/{worksheetName}/pivotTables/refreshAll
I have also programmed the equivalent in C#. I get the same result whether or not I utilize sessions. I get no errors in any case - just a 204 No Content return. Even waiting for some time doesn't seem to yield any results. I can successfully list out the pivot tables on the worksheet by removing the refreshAll, so I don't seem to have any sort of access issues or malformed URL issue. Additionally, I have checked the checkbox under the connections tab that allows for "Refresh All" actions to be used on the pivot table.
Finally, as a last tidbit of information, I have tried to refresh the pivot table individually. I get a 500 error within my C# code and within my CURL attempts, but a 204 using the Graph Explorer that still does nothing.
Are there any work-arounds? I have also tried using COM objects within C#, but I cannot, for the life of me, figure out how to silently authenticate via the COM objects.

It turns out that the Graph API doesn't have functionality that I was trying to achieve. RefreshAll doesn't mean Refreshing connections, just pulling new information into my pivot tables if their data source has been refreshed. I stripped the PowerBI connections that I was trying to pull new information out of and swapped to a database connection and resorting to using Excel.Interop to refresh those connections, as I can do that silently.
